# Unable to use SSL certificate when using Android Oreo connected to Charles 4.1.4 proxy

Tags: ssl-certificate, charles-proxy, android-8.0-oreo

All requests and responses in Charles appear encrypted even after installing SSL certificate in Android Oreo device.

Device gets connected to charles proxy and packets are observed. However, all information are encrypted and cannot be seen in plain-text. Query Parameters are hence not visible and so are the server responses.

Charles version: 4.1.4
Android version in device: Oreo
Device: Nexus 6P

Comment: try setting proxy in source?

Comment: Using latest Oreo version and Charles 4.2.x, this issue can no longer be reproduced.

Ensure SSL Proxying is enabled if the problem still persists.